# Trying to print out the binary conversion of an integer

Tags: binary

I'm trying to convert an integer into its binary format.

My code has a bug because it seems to work when I use integers like 32, 20, 9, etc, but for 529, it doesn't print out the last number. Can someone please help review my faulty code?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    // create your values
    int number = get_int("Number to convert: ");
    // divide the values and get remainder
    int i = 0;
    int div = 2;
    int num;
    for (i = 0; i <= number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= number; j++)
        {

            int remainder = (number % div);
            num = (number / div);
            number = num;
            printf("%d", remainder);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");`
```